# XML Expression Binding - Proceed Code in conditional operator

Tags: sapui5

I am currently working on a Fiori app. At the moment I try to set a title depending on the value of a property I get from my OData service. Therefore I want to use expression binding with the conditional operator.

So when `${PROPERTIY}` has the value `"EXAMPLE"`, it should print the value of `OUTPUT_PROPERTY_1`. Otherwise, it should print the value of `OUTPUT_PROPERTY_2`.

XML:

```xml
<ObjectListItem title="{= ${PROPERTIY} === 'EXAMPLE' ? '${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_1}' : '${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_2}'}">
```

Unfortunately, it just prints `${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_1}` or `${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_2}`, and does not proceed the code to get the actual value of the properties.

Is there any chance to solve this problem or even a good workaround in order to print the actual value of the related property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes around the expression binding syntax:

```
title="{= ${PROPERTIY} === 'EXAMPLE' ? ${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_1} : ${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_2}}"
```

Otherwise, `'${OUTPUT_PROPERTY_x}'` will be treated as a string literal.